# Auto rows based on content in column

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: layout]

Hey,

i am trying to achieve this kind of layout with css grid.
I have set the container div of these items to
`display: grid`and `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`. Then i layed out the items with grid-column and grid row.
This gives me an 3x3 grid. But i need a grid with 2 rows in the first column, 3 rows in the middle column and two rows in the third column. Based on the size of the item. Is there any way of doing this with css grid, i am stuck at the moment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can take up to 2 spaces with `grid-row: span 2;`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.gr2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box gr2">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box gr2">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```